# special characters and chinese fonts inserting in jsp page not working in spring controller

Tags: java, string, spring, jsp, utf-8

abc.jsp page.   i  am trying to insert chines fonts in the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

```
<form id="bform"  action="addemo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class='form-group' accept-charset="utf-8">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>Book Image</label> <input type='file' name="file"
                                    class='btn' required="required" id="image_file"
                                    onchange="return validateimage();"> <img
                                    src="img/user_default_large.png" alt="" id="uploadPreview"
                                    style="height: 130px; width: 21%;">
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label>Book Title</label> <input type='text' name='title'
                                    class='form-control'  placeholder='Title' required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <input type='Submit' name='cat_img' value='Add'
                                    class='btn btn-success'> <input type='reset'
                                    name='cat_img' value='Cancel' class='btn btn-primary'>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

In the above form when i am  adding chinese fonts "你好"
and submitting the form request goes to controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addemo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JSONObject view(HttpServletRequest request,@Valid Books model, BindingResult results,
            @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile image) throws ExecutionException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        String username = request.getParameter("title");
        System.out.println("encoding: "+request.getCharacterEncoding());
        System.out.println("received: "+username);
        System.out.println("received: "+username);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        System.out.println(model.getTitle());
```

i am getting this on my console
encoding: utf-8
received: ä½ å¥½
received: ä½ å¥½
ä½ å¥½
ä½ å¥½

How should i get the utf-8 encoded data in a string params .
please explain.

Comment: you need to set encoding utf-8 for your console

Comment: Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.
    Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".

but it is not working. @RizwanM.Tuman

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at UTF-8 support in the following areas:

URLs, 
Apache, 
HTML, 
JavaScript, 
POST data
File download, 
JSPs, 
Java code, 
Tomcat, 
Oracle, 
File system

Go through the following link that might help u :- http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/kieranshaw/entry/utf-8_internationalisation_with/